# Calculating number of pixels with different values

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have a tiff where each pixel has a value in megagrams for biomass.
I'm trying to get a count of the pixels for all the pixels with diffrent megagrams values so that I can get an estimation of biomass.

How do I go about this in QGIS 3.2?

Comment: Try the [zonal statistics tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254974/how-does-zonal-statistics-work-exactly).

Comment: How do I get zonal stats tool in qgis 3.2? I can't find it in any toolbox or in the plugin menu

Comment: processing toolbox

Comment: Load the Processing Plugin (core plugin, may be already loaded), then open the Processing Toolbox ([CTRL]+[ALT]+T) and enter zonal into the search bar. then start "zonal statistics"

Comment: All I have is a raster file but the Zonal stats tool tells me I need a vector layer to run any stats